# How can I get virtualenv to produce Python executables with the correct sys.path using the Enthought Python Distribution?

Tags: python, virtualenv, enthought

I installed the Enthought Python Distribution version 7.0 on a Mac, then easy_installed pip, then did pip install virtualenv. When I try to create a virtual environment, I get:

```
> virtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
ERROR: The executable test/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0' (should be '/Users/anand/test')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable`
```

and test/bin does not contain any activate script. How can I get virtualenv working?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would be interested in knowing the answer to this too!

Answer (score 6):

This question was discussed on the EPD developers mailing list.
Among others it was mentioned that EPD was not put together with virtualenv in mind and that it has it's bugs sometimes.
However, somebody posted a link to a summarized solution which I'm trying out myself now:
https://gist.github.com/845545

HTH,
Michael

Comment: Note, that the newest rendition of Enthought, called Canopy, seems to actively use virtualenv inside.